# BOX2D - implicit conversion of NULL constant to 'bool' [-Wnull-conversion]

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, box2d

I am trying to compile Box2D to 64 bit version for android using android ndk

however I am getting loads of errors like this one:

> andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/src/main/jni\Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2ChainShape.h:111:20: warning: implicit conversion of NULL constant to 'bool' [-Wnull-conversion]
>           m_hasPrevVertex = NULL;
>                           ~ ^~~~
>                             false

Thats content of my b2ChainShape.h

```
/*
* Copyright (c) 2006-2010 Erin Catto http://www.box2d.org
*
* This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
* warranty.  In no event will the authors be held liable for any damages
* arising from the use of this software.
* Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
* including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
* freely, subject to the following restrictions:
* 1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
* claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this software
* in a product, an acknowledgment in the product documentation would be
* appreciated but is not required.
* 2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
* misrepresented as being the original software.
* 3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
*/

#ifndef B2_CHAIN_SHAPE_H
#define B2_CHAIN_SHAPE_H

#include <Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2Shape.h>

class b2EdgeShape;

/// A chain shape is a free form sequence of line segments.
/// The chain has two-sided collision, so you can use inside and outside collision.
/// Therefore, you may use any winding order.
/// Since there may be many vertices, they are allocated using b2Alloc.
/// Connectivity information is used to create smooth collisions.
/// WARNING: The chain will not collide properly if there are self-intersections.
class b2ChainShape : public b2Shape
{
public:
    b2ChainShape();

    /// The destructor frees the vertices using b2Free.
    ~b2ChainShape();

    /// Create a loop. This automatically adjusts connectivity.
    /// @param vertices an array of vertices, these are copied
    /// @param count the vertex count
    void CreateLoop(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 count);

    /// Create a chain with isolated end vertices.
    /// @param vertices an array of vertices, these are copied
    /// @param count the vertex count
    void CreateChain(const b2Vec2* vertices, int32 count);

    /// Establish connectivity to a vertex that precedes the first vertex.
    /// Don't call this for loops.
    void SetPrevVertex(const b2Vec2& prevVertex);

    /// Establish connectivity to a vertex that follows the last vertex.
    /// Don't call this for loops.
    void SetNextVertex(const b2Vec2& nextVertex);

    /// Implement b2Shape. Vertices are cloned using b2Alloc.
    b2Shape* Clone(b2BlockAllocator* allocator) const;

    /// @see b2Shape::GetChildCount
    int32 GetChildCount() const;

    /// Get a child edge.
    void GetChildEdge(b2EdgeShape* edge, int32 index) const;

    /// This always return false.
    /// @see b2Shape::TestPoint
    bool TestPoint(const b2Transform& transform, const b2Vec2& p) const;

    /// Implement b2Shape.
    bool RayCast(b2RayCastOutput* output, const b2RayCastInput& input,
                    const b2Transform& transform, int32 childIndex) const;

    /// @see b2Shape::ComputeAABB
    void ComputeAABB(b2AABB* aabb, const b2Transform& transform, int32 childIndex) const;

    /// Chains have zero mass.
    /// @see b2Shape::ComputeMass
    void ComputeMass(b2MassData* massData, float32 density) const;

    /// Get the number of vertices.
    int32 GetVertexCount() const { return m_count; }

    /// Get the vertices (read-only).
    const b2Vec2& GetVertex(int32 index) const
    {
        b2Assert(0 <= index && index < m_count);
        return m_vertices[index];
    }

    /// Get the vertices (read-only).
    const b2Vec2* GetVertices() const { return m_vertices; }

    /// The vertices. Owned by this class.
    b2Vec2* m_vertices;

    /// The vertex count.
    int32 m_count;

    b2Vec2 m_prevVertex, m_nextVertex;
    bool m_hasPrevVertex, m_hasNextVertex;
};

inline b2ChainShape::b2ChainShape()
{
    m_type = e_chain;
    m_radius = b2_polygonRadius;
    m_vertices = NULL;
    m_count = 0;
    m_hasPrevVertex = NULL;
    m_hasNextVertex = NULL;
}

#endif
```

Any suggestion would be apprecieated

Comment: Why are you setting your booleans `m_hasPrevVertex` and `m_hasNextVertex` to `NULL` instead of just `false`? That's what the warning is about

Comment: @Qbrute - that was original code from box2d branch, no idea why it was like that, but following your suggestion (which is logical) solved it, thank you!

Comment: If you post your response as a answer, I can accept it, regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you got here

> implicit conversion of NULL constant to 'bool' [-Wnull-conversion] m_hasPrevVertex = NULL; ~ ^~~~ false

tells you, that you have `bool` fields that are initialized with `NULL` instead of an actual boolean value. For example `m_hasPrevVertex` and `m_hasNextVertex`. So the compiler tries to fix this by implicitly setting those values to `false` instead and by notifying you about that fact.

It's not a critical error in this case, but definitely a code smell. (Although, maybe different compilers would actually throw an error here, I'm not sure)

You can get rid of these warnings by simply initializing all your bools to either `true` or `false`, depending on your use case.